# Hide "Save for use in other apps" toggle in Stripe iOS Payment Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I am using the default Stripe credit card form and it has the toggle at the bottom that says "Save for use in other apps"

Is there any way to hide this option without remaking my own custom form?

I've looked through the docs and couldn't find any API reference for this.

---

For a little code reference/context: I am using the [Stripe iOS SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and am calling the `presentPaymentMethodsViewController` method on `STPPaymentContext`.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Thanks, all!

Comment: Hi @wyzkid207, did you found a solution for above?

Comment: @KanakSony I didn't find any solution using the standard stripe API but I did find this project https://github.com/prolificinteractive/Caishen that could be used for the UI and then use Stripe's custom integration (https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom). I decided to just ignore it and use the default Stripe interface. Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn that toggle off by disabling `smsAutofillDisabled`, like this:

`STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().smsAutofillDisabled = true`